# Crystal Reports maximum(date,customer) what about other fields in that record

Tags: crystal-reports, max, min, crystal-reports-2008

I am using Crystal Reports 2008 and trying to get other fields associated with maximum(date,customer).

Data:

```
customer    orderdate   item
'1'         '1/1/2014'   '87'
'1'     '1/2/2014'    '99'  
'1'     '1/3/2014'    '21'  
'1'     '1/4/2014'    '55'
...
```

report to show

```
'Customer' 'maxOrderDate'  'maxOrderDateitem'  'minOrderDate''minOrderdateItem'
```

I've grouped by customer and have max and min dates in the group header [min date I'm getting by arranging details ascending]. Order data in details sorted ascending. Formula for maximum: maximum(orderDate, customer). Is it even possible to get the other data on that line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can get try below formula:

```
if orderdate=Maximum(orderdate)
then item
```

Place the above formula after max date and in the same way create for min date

Comment: No dice, this formula gave me a blank... I guess I'll live without it. First records are worlds more important than last.. Both would be nice. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: Where did you place the formula?

Comment: in group header, with the other data

Answer (score 0):

Well simply again group by the Date and choose the Ascending or descending order as per your need.
In that the look would be: (According to the Group Heirarchy, you can also change the group order)

```
Customer............................................................
Date...............................................................
//place all other fields here and they will be according to the respective dates.
```